# MariaDB - cannot set max_connections through my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am struggling to set max_connections parameter in /etc/my.cnf but MariaDB does not seem to read the parameter from the file.

My /etc/my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
#skip-grant-tables
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# network
connect_timeout = 60
wait_timeout = 28800
max_connections = 100000
max_allowed_packet = 64M
max_connect_errors = 1000

# limits
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
table_cache = 512

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

[client]
port = 3306
socket= /data/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But when I check the variable in MariaDB, it shows the default value:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 214   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, other parameters in my.cnf are correct:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 67108864 |
+--------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'max_connect_errors';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| max_connect_errors | 1000  |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'connect_timeout';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| connect_timeout | 60    |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can set this variable from mysql command line but it resets itself when I restart the service:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set global max_connections := 10000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 10000 |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

OS: RHEL 7

MariaDB version: mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64

See here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137487/mariadb-cannot-set-max-connections-and-wait-timeout-through-my-cnf

Comment: are you sure that's the used config file? modify another config param and see if that modification gets reflected at runtime

Comment: I am sure. Checked it.

Comment: It is possible that there are other my.cnf files on your system that overwrite the max_connections param. Check in the locations that mariadb also looks in: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/

Comment: /etc/my.cnf.d/ contains some conf files but they are empty (no parameters set). Also, I did a search with find / -name *.cnf and checked all files I could find...

Comment: Please crosslink this question with the other copy of it.

Comment: Answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137487/mariadb-cannot-set-max-connections-and-wait-timeout-through-my-cnf

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is here. Increase your open files limit .

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12061/mysql-auto-adjusting-max-connections-values

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue on ubuntu server. nd i have change this file  /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
max_connections = 1000
```

then execute the query .
you are changing wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu server with Maria DB enter parameter *max connections* in */etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf*

Restart the service for changes to take effect.

```
systemctl restart mariadb
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - I know - necromancy - but there's no better answer so here goes:

I had been plagued with this issue myself for a terribly long time.  However, just today, I came to the realisation that sometimes the comments inside configuration files can be helpful.  Namely, the directory identified in line number `2.` below found in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf`:

```sh
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
```

So, you need to add your global options to a section named `[mysqld]` into a file such as `/etc/mysql/conf.d/myoptions.cnf`

Restart MariaDB and your settings will stick.